# How To Call Multisend Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, erc-20

If I have the contract with the code

```
contract Airdropper is Ownable {

function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256[] values)
onlyOwner
returns (uint256) {
    uint256 i = 0;
    while (i < dests.length) {
        ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], values[i]);
        i += 1;
    }
    return(i);
}
}
```

How would I call it (how would I create the array, where does the token need to be stored)?
Also, how many transactions could I do at once before it will cause issues? Is it unlimited? Could I do 10,000 at once saving tens of thousands of dollars of gas?

I am willing to hire someone to do this for me and I will pay them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have built Multisender Dapp:
https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender/#/

Source code: 
https://github.com/rstormsf/multisender/blob/master/contracts/contracts/multisender/UpgradebleStormSender.sol

```
function multisendToken(address token, address[] _contributors, uint256[] _balances) public hasFee payable {
    uint256 total = 0;
    require(_contributors.length <= arrayLimit());
    ERC20 erc20token = ERC20(token);
    uint8 i = 0;
    for (i; i < _contributors.length; i++) {
        erc20token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _contributors[i], _balances[i]);
        total += _balances[i];
    }
    setTxCount(msg.sender, txCount(msg.sender).add(1));
    Multisended(total, token);
}
```

Comment: Would this save any gas?

Comment: @James no, it doesn't save any  gas, it only saves you time.