# Are transactions in a BatchRequest guaranteed to be in the same block?

Tags: web3js

I'm sending 0.1 ETH to 10 different addresses from the same address with manually incremented nonces in a `BatchRequest`. So far on Kovan, all transactions in the same `BatchRequest` have entered the same block, which is precisely the behavior I need.

Are these `BatchRequest` transactions *always guaranteed* to be in the same block, whether on Kovan or Mainnet?

Edit: The answer is no. I tried with ~700 addresses and only so many (~81) can fit in a single block.

Comment: Probably not. Try to increase it from 10 transactions to 100 and see what happens.

Comment: BTW, if you want to ensure that it is done from the same block, then implement and deploy a contract with a function which takes an array of addresses and an array of amounts as input, and transfers from `msg.sender` each one of the input amounts to the corresponding address. Of course, you will need to pass `msg.value` equal to the sum of those amounts when you call this function (so declare it `payable`).

Comment: BTW2, in addition to ensuring that it is executed in the same block, it will also save you a lot of gas.

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to listen for confirmations on those transfers? Or would I just listen for confirmations on that one contract call? Once each of the 10 recipients receives the 0.1 ETH (after 12 confs or so), I need to trigger a second action on those recipients.

Comment: Also, are you sure such a contract would save gas? According to the author of this multisend contract (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/51612/60011), it would only save time.